# Converting a string representation of dicts to an actual dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file with 100K+ lines of data in this format:

```
"{'foo':'bar' , 'foo1':'bar1', 'foo3':'bar3'}"


"{'foo':'bar' , 'foo1':'bar1', 'foo4':'bar4'}"
```

The quotes are there before the curly braces because my data came in a CSV file.

I want to extract the key value pairs in all the lines to create a dataframe like so:

```
Column Headers: foo, foo1, foo3, foo...


Rows:           bar, bar1, bar3, bar...
```

I've tried implementing something similar to what's explained here ( [Python: error parsing strings from text file with Ast module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270031/python-error-parsing-strings-from-text-file-with-ast-module)).

I've gotten the ast.literal_eval function to work on my file to convert the contents into a dict but now how do I get the DataFrame function to work? I am very much a beginner so any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

with open('file_name.csv') as f:
        for string in f:
            parsed = ast.literal_eval(string.rstrip())
            print(parsed)


pd.DataFrame(???)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Follow this append the dict from every row in the dataframe.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43957800/6863323

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a dictionary into a pandas dataframe using pd.DataFrame.from_dict, but it will expect each value in the dictionary to be in a list.

```py
for key, value in parsed.items():
   parsed[key] = [value]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parsed)
```

You can do this iteratively by appending to your dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for string in f:
    parsed = ast.literal_eval(string.rstrip())
    for key, value in parsed.items():
        parsed[key] = [value]
    df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parsed))
```

Answer (score 0):

`parsed` is a dictionary, you make a dataframe from it, then join all the frames together:

```
df = []
with open('file_name.csv') as f:
    for string in f:
        parsed = ast.literal_eval(string.rstrip())
        if type(parsed) != dict:
            continue

        subDF = pd.DataFrame(parsed, index=[0])
        df.append(subDF)

df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Calling `pd.concat` on a list of dataframes is faster than calling `DataFrame.append` repeatedly. `sort=False` means that `pd.concat` will not sort the column names when it encounters a few one, like `foo4` on the second row.

Comment: This makes sense! I tried this out and got a ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! error. Perhaps because parsed is still being treated as a string? 

When I tried checking type(parsed) str was returned.

Comment: That appears to be the bug. May be ignore the line if `parsed` cannot be converted into a dict?

Comment: This is something I've noticed. I can individually add a line from my data set and it gets converted into a dict when I run ast.literal_eval on it. But when I try ast.literal_eval on the file as a whole, and check type() afterwards, str is returned.

Comment: Which line should I ignore?